# Sort rows of cell array and leave out first row (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, row, cell-array

I have a cell array with 2 columns. The first row consists of strings which describe the x and the y data. The remaining rows consist of numbers. I would like to sort the data by the x data ascending. The problem is the first line. Is there a command to leave out the first line with i.e. `sortrows`.

Comment: If your first row is irrelevant, why don't you just delete it?

Comment: please give a numerical example of input and desired ouput

Comment: Is the problem that you want to keep the first row and sort the rest?

Comment: It is as patrik said: I would like to keep the first row and sort the rest

Comment: Try to use sub referencing, `a = {'x','y';1,2;5,1;3,4}; a(2:end,:) = sortrows(a(2:end,:),1)`

Comment: It works now with subreferencing. Thank you

Comment: Have you thought about replacing each cell with a `Table` since you're giving them a manual header row at the moment anyways. And I'm sure that `table`s come with built-in sort methods